# embedding a text file in an exe which can be accessed using fopen

Tags: c++, header

I would like to embed a text file with some data into my program. 
let's call it "*data.txt*".

This text file is usually loaded with a function which requires the text file's file name as input and is eventually opened using a fopen() call... some something to the lines of

```
FILE* name = fopen("data.txt");
```

I can't really change this function and I would like the routine to open this same file every time it runs. I've seen people ask about embedding the file as a header but it seems that I wouldn't be able to call fopen() on a file that I embed into the header.

So my question is: is there a way to embed a text file as a callable file/variable to fopen()?

I am using VS2008.

Comment: Why not ifstream? Or even better, istringstream? Why are you still using fopen?

Comment: Embed the file as a char-array in a headerfile, ,write it to a file when the program starts to a file called "data.txt", then you can open it as above

Comment: the function call is not my code, and I can't modify it for my purposes, so I'm stuck with using fopen

Answer (score 2):

Yes and No. The easiest way is to transform the content of the text file into an initialized array.

```
char data_txt[] = {
    'd','a','t','a',' ','g','o','e','s',' ','h','e','r','e', //....
};
```

This transformation is easily done with a small perl script or even a small C program. You then compile and link the resulting module into your program.

An old trick to make this easier to manage with a Makefile is to make the script transform its data into the *body* of the initializer and write it to a file without the surrounding variable declaration or even the curly braces. If `data.txt` is transformed to `data.inc`, then it is used like so:

```
char data_txt[] = {
#include "data.inc"
};
```

**Update**

On many platforms, it is possible to append arbitrary data to the executable file itself. The trick then is to find it at run time. On platforms where this is possible, there will be file header information for the executable that indicates the length of the executable image. That can be used to compute an offset to use with `fseek()` after you have opened the executable file for reading. That is harder to do in a portable way, since it may not even be possible to learn the actual file name of your executable image at run time in a portable way. (Hint, `argv[0]` is not required to point to the actual program.)

If you cannot avoid the call to `fopen()`, then you can still use this trick to keep a copy of the content of `data.txt`, and put it back in a file at run time. You could even be clever and only write the file if it is missing....

If you can drop the call to `fopen()` but still need a `FILE *` pointing at the data, then this is likely possible *if* you are willing to play fast and loose with your C runtime library's implementation of stdio. In the GNU version of libc, functions like `sprintf()` and `sscanf()` are actually implemented by creating a "real enough" `FILE *` that can be passed to a common implementation (`vfprintf()` and `vfscanf()`, IIRC). That faked `FILE` is marked as buffered, and points its buffer to the users's buffer. Some magic is used to make sure the rest of stdio doesn't do anything stupid.

Comment: I guess OP has a lot of code that uses `FILE*` and tries to avoid modifying this code

Comment: its probably possible to create your own `FILE` to point at that has the initialized data array as its buffer, and smells like it is an open, buffered, read-only stream.

Comment: Why would it be necessary to separate the file contents into character literals? Couldn't you just make sure each line begins and ends with a quote, quotes (and perhaps other such characters) in the text are escaped and newline symbols inserted?

Comment: @Andy T: yes, you are correct Andy, I can't modify the code atm.

Comment: @UncleBens, you can represent the text in a variety of ways, just so the result is a legal C initializer. When I use this technique in practice, I'm usually building a binary blob, so my `bin2c` tool writes out an array of byte values in hex. Its not human readable at all, and that doesn't matter because it is derived at build time from the actual source file. I used character constants in my example to emphasize that you can't just `#include` the text file itself.

Answer (score 0):

**For any kind of file**, base on RBerteig anwser you could do something simple as this with python:

This program will generate a text.txt.c file that can be compiled and linked to your code, to embed any text or binary file directly to your exe and read it directly from a variable:

```
import struct;                  #    Needed to convert string to byte

f = open("text.txt","rb")       #    Open the file in read binary mode
s = "unsigned char text_txt_data[] = {"

b = f.read(1)                   #    Read one byte from the stream
db = struct.unpack("b",b)[0]     #    Transform it to byte
h = hex(db)                      #    Generate hexadecimal string
s = s + h;                      #    Add it to the final code
b = f.read(1)                   #    Read one byte from the stream

while b != "":
    s = s + ","                 #    Add a coma to separate the array
    db = struct.unpack("b",b)[0] #    Transform it to byte
    h = hex(db)                  #    Generate hexadecimal string
    s = s + h;                  #    Add it to the final code
    b = f.read(1)               #    Read one byte from the stream

s = s + "};"                     #    Close the bracktes
f.close()                       #    Close the file

# Write the resultan code to a file that can be compiled
fw = open("text.txt.c","w");   
fw.write(s);
fw.close();
```

Will generate something like

```
unsigned char text_txt_data[] = {0x52,0x61,0x6e,0x64,0x6f,0x6d,0x20,0x6e,0x75...
```

You can latter use your data in another c file using the variable with a code like this:

extern unsigned char text_txt_data[];

Right now I cant think of two ways to converting it to readable text. Using memory streams or converting it to a c-string.